# On change event is not triggering before i click outside the form field

Tags: jquery

I have two form fields that I am controlling with this jQuery code

This is the html code

```js
$('form :input').change(function() {
  var pickup = $("#pickup").val();
  var destination = $("#destination").val();

  if (pickup !== "" && destination !== "") {
    console.log("all filed");
  } else {
    console.log("change but not filled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="order">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
    <label for="pickup">Pickup Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="pickup" id="pickup" class="form-control form-field" placeholder="Pickup Location" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
    <label for="destination">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-field" id="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Destination" required>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" disabled>Confirm Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I fill the fields with some data and i fill both fields, the event is thrown immediately that the two form fields are filled but when i delete some of the data in any of the form fields, i have to click outside the form field for the event to be triggered. Is there a way i can make sure the event is triggered immediately?.

Update to include places api

```
var pickup = document.getElementById('pickup');
var destintion = document.getElementById('destination');
var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'nl'}};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup, options);
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination, options);

$('form :input').on('input', function() { 
   var pickup = $("#pickup").val();
   var destination = $("#destination").val();

   if(pickup !== "" && destination !== "") {
   console.log("all filed");
   }
   else{
   console.log("change but not filled");
   }
});
```

Comment: you can use `.on('input' ,` instead of `.change()` .. but I think `.on('input'` in this case will cause a lot of problems .. in your case you need to `blur`

Comment: Change event won't occur until you blur away from the field. No way to reproduce behavior you describe getting event to trigger before you blur. Perhaps you have some other event listeners also?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef on input works but its a bit of a problem for auto complete. I am suing google places auto complete.

Comment: @charlietfl I dont have other listeners

Comment: I created a runnable snippet in this page and it does not exhibit that behavior. You must blur away from each field to get event to trigger

Comment: works but i have to click outside the form field.I have updated with code that includes places api.

Comment: Of course you have to click outside.  As has been said, "change" fires after the field is blurred.

Comment: Hmm, i never did that

Comment: It was not an additional question. I was just showing the code i am using google places that was triggering too soon.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the autocomplete that wasn't originally shown which would also add it's own listeners

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, the autocomplete must have its own listener as well  but the api is not straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code:

```js
$('form :input').on('input', function() {
  var pickup = $("#pickup").val();
  var destination = $("#destination").val();

  if (pickup !== "" && destination !== "") {
    console.log("all filed");
  } else {
    console.log("change but not filled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="order">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
    <label for="pickup">Pickup Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="pickup" id="pickup" class="form-control form-field" placeholder="Pickup Location" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
    <label for="destination">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-field" id="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Destination" required>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" disabled>Confirm Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why keyup instead of input?

Comment: No, `keyup` literally fires for every keyup.  This includes arrow keys, and other keys that do not change the actual value of the field.  `input` only fires when the value changes, and will fire before the `blur` happens.

Comment: The point being keyup will do the same thing as input, but in cases where it really should not, as there's no actual work to do for the keys that do not change the value.

Comment: yes I understand. But I have mentioned on whose keyup it should work. Thats why I have answered it as keyup. And yes you are right we can use input. In this case keyup and input should work as same. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: It's always important to be aware of when you are writing logic that is causing the system to perform more work than necessary.